# Generate mongodb compatible id using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, mongodb

I want to serialize a class and store its representation on server in MongoDB.Each class instance has a unique id. This id has to be compatible with MongoDB id format so that I can put it directly in the db. I was able to do it in Backbone.js (javascript) using this plugin https://github.com/ask11/backbone-id. I am wondering if there's a way I can generate mongodb compatible ids in Objective C?

Comment: If you can ensure that a key is unique, just call it '_id' and mongodb will accept it, independently of its type. It does not need to be in the mongo default format.

Comment: @innoSPG thanks for your answer. You are correct but I still want my ids to be compatible with ObjectID format. I have found a solution. I will post it as an answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the solution mentioned here : http://bit.ly/15uvHTo. The code in this gist uses "[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]" which is deprecated since iOS5 so I used OpenUDID (https://github.com/xaviermichel/OpenUDID) instead.